# Can this two IP see each other?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, mask

I can't remember how networking worked. I need someone to help me with this, it may sound a bit stupid but I have to take care.
This are the two IPs:

- 107.1.233.7/24
- 10.202.104.148/25

Simple question.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "see each other"? The question is vague, please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

> Can this two IP see each other?

No, 107.1.233.7 isn't in the range 10.202.104.148/25 and 10.202.104.148 isn't in the range 107.1.233.0/24

Answer (score 1):

To be clearer with the Answer

To identify, whether an IP is real or not, IANA is always the first way you can verify it.

#### Route able Address ([Public Networks](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml)):

[107/8](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml) is an internet route able IP.
It can be reached directly.
And is owned by [ARIN and managed by Comcast](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-107-0-0-0-1/pft?s=107.1.233.7).

#### Non Route Able Addresses ([Private Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)):

- 10/8
- 192.168/16 (to be honestly, yes, they are multiple times 255 a /24)
- 172.16/16

They are so called [Private Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and is a "non route able" [Special Purposes Address Space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). These addresses exist to be used on Home-Networks or usually called [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network).

All Addresses could co-exist on the same [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) if required. I.e. for [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or [Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing).

To let these IPs see the 107's ip, it requires a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

##### Conclusion:

Technically said,

- it might be possible Yes,
- but in fact, without a trick No.

i hope i could bring it a bit better to your question. :-)
I would be glad if this would be the accepted answer

Comment: Private addresses routable indeed, but not globaly reachable.

Comment: from the global aspect they can't, locally they can, i agree ;)